Authentication in Blazor Webassembly project which hosted on ASP.NET Core 8 project
I try to implement Microsoft Login in my Blazor Web App project. I get an exception when I try to click the button - Login - I get an error:

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IRemoteAuthenticationService`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c__1<TRemoteAuthenticationState>.<AddAuthenticationStateProvider>b__1_0(IServiceProvider sp)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType, IComponentRenderMode callerSpecifiedRenderMode, Nullable<int> parentComponentId)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] frames, int frameIndex, int parentComponentId)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(ref DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int newFrameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(ref DiffContext diffContext, int oldStartIndex, int oldEndIndexExcl, int newStartIndex, int newEndIndexExcl)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, int componentId, ArrayRange<RenderTreeFrame> oldTree, ArrayRange<RenderTreeFrame> newTree)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, out Exception renderFragmentException)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(IComponent component, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.RenderEndpointComponent(HttpContext httpContext, Type rootComponentType, ParameterView parameters, bool waitForQuiescence)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c+<<InvokeAsync>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OB_RappInter_CheckList_DotNet8.Client.Pages;
using OB_RappInter_CheckList_DotNet8.Components;
using OB_RappInter_CheckList_DotNet8.Services;
using OB_RappInter_CheckList_DotNet8.Data;
using Syncfusion.Blazor;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<INavDataStatoCommessa, NavDataStatoCommessa>();

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});

Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("Ngo9BigBOggjHTQxAR8/V1NBaF5cXmZCf1FpRmJGdld5fUVHYVZUTXxaS00DNHVRdkdnWXtedHRRQ2dZWEV3Wko=");
builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(OB_RappInter_CheckList_DotNet8.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.Run();

Routes.razor:
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                        {
                            <RedirectToLogin />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p role="alert">Non sei autorizzato ad accedere a questa risorsa.</p>
                        }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <CascadingAuthenticationState>
                <PageTitle>Non Trovato</PageTitle>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
                    <p role="alert">Mi spiace, non c'è niente a questo indirizzo.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </CascadingAuthenticationState>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

App.razor:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OB_RappInter_CheckList_DotNet8.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="png/Logo_O.png" />
    <link href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/SCSS-Bootstrap5/bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/Icons_bi/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/Icons_oi/font/css/open-iconic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.PdfViewer/scripts/syncfusion-blazor-pdfviewer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.min.js";
    </script>
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

